# Confusing output from String.split

Tags: java, string, split

I do not understand the output of this code:

```
public class StringDemo{              
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String blank = "";                    
        String comma = ",";                   
        System.out.println("Output1: "+blank.split(",").length);  
        System.out.println("Output2: "+comma.split(",").length);  
    }
}
```

And got the following output:

```
Output1: 1 
Output2: 0
```

Comment: What do you not understand about it?

Comment: @Raedwald Confusing part was that `",".split(",")` could return `["",""]` array but it returns `[]` (empty array - length 0 - because `split(",",0)` trails empty Strings at the end). So why empty string in result array was not trailed in case of `"",split(",")`?

Comment: The weirdness of `String.split` is exactly why the Guava library has `Splitter`, as [explained in the Guava documentation](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter)

Answer (score 55):

Documentation:

For: `System.out.println("Output1: "+blank.split(",").length);`

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the string. The substrings in the array are in the order in which they occur in this string. **If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string**.

It will simply return the entire string that's why it returns 1.

---

For the second case, `String.split` will discard the `,` so the result will be empty.

```
String.split silently discards trailing separators
```

see [guava StringsExplained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter) too

Comment: The Javadoc of the one-argument split method says: "This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**" That's the correct explanation of the second result. Two trailing empty strings get excluded.

Comment: Yeah, in theory everything is in doc. But I always wonder from where they are getting those guys that you can read 10 times what they've written, and yet still you have to write a test program to understand what that method is actually doing...

Answer (score 35):

Everything happens according to plan, but let's do it step by step (I hope you have some time).

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) (and [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#2408)) of `split(String regex)` method:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero.

So when you invoke

```
split(String regex)
```

you are actually getting result from the `split(String regex, int limit)` method which is invoked in a way:

```
split(regex, 0)
```

So here `limit` is set to `0`.

You need to know a few things about this parameter:

- If `limit` is positive you are limiting length of result array to a positive number you specified, so `"axaxaxaxa".split("x",2)` will return an array, `["a", "axaxaxa"]`, not `["a","a","a","a","a"]`.
- If `limit` is `0` then you are not limiting the length of the result array. But it also means that any trailing empty strings will be removed. For example:

  ```
  "fooXbarX".split("X")
  ```

  will at start generate an array which will look like:

  ```
  ["foo", "bar", ""]
  ```

  (`"barX"` split on `"X"` generates `"bar"` and `""`), but since `split` removes all trailing empty string, it will return

  ```
  ["foo", "bar"]
  ```
- Behaviour of negative value of `limit` is similar to behaviour where limit is set to `0` (it will not limit length of result array). The only difference is that it will not remove empty strings from the end of the result array. In other words

  ```
  "fooXbarX".split("X",-1)
  ```

will return `["foo", "bar", ""]`

---

Lets take a look at the case,

```
",".split(",").length
```

which (as explained earlier) is same as

```
",".split(",", 0).length
```

This means that we are using a version of split which will not limit the length of the result array, but ***will remove all trailing empty strings***, `""`. You need to understand that when we split *one* thing we are always getting *two* things.

In other words, if we split `"abc"` in place of `b`, we will get `"a"` and `"c"`.
The tricky part is to understand that if we split `"abc"` in `c` we will get `"ab"` and `""` (empty string).

Using this logic, if we split `","` on `,` we will get `""` and `""` (two empty strings).

You can check it using `split` with negative limit:

```
for (String s: ",".split(",", -1)){
    System.out.println("\""+s+"\"");
}
```

which will print

```
""
""
```

So as we see result array here is at first `["", ""]`.

But since by default we are using `limit` set to `0`, all trailing empty strings will be removed. In this case, the result array contains *only trailing empty strings*, so **all of them will be removed**, leaving you with empty array `[]` which has length `0`.

---

To answer the case with

```
"".split(",").length
```

you need to understand that **removing trailing empty strings makes sense only if such trailing empty strings ware *result of splitting* (and most probably are not needed)**.
So if there were not any places on which we could split, there is no chance that empty strings ware created, so there is no point in running this "cleaning" process.

This information is mentioned in [documentation of `split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) method where you can read:

> If the expression **does not match any part of the input** then the **resulting array has just one element, namely this string**.

You can also see this behaviour in [source code of this method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#2316) (from Java 8):

```
2316      public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
2317          /* fastpath if the regex is a
2318           (1)one-char String and this character is not one of the
2319              RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or
2320           (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and
2321              the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.
2322           */
2323          char ch = 0;
2324          if (((regex.value.length == 1 &&
2325               ".$|()[{^?*+\\".indexOf(ch = regex.charAt(0)) == -1) ||
2326               (regex.length() == 2 &&
2327                regex.charAt(0) == '\\' &&
2328                (((ch = regex.charAt(1))-'0')|('9'-ch)) < 0 &&
2329                ((ch-'a')|('z'-ch)) < 0 &&
2330                ((ch-'A')|('Z'-ch)) < 0)) &&
2331              (ch < Character.MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE ||
2332               ch > Character.MAX_LOW_SURROGATE))
2333          {
2334              int off = 0;
2335              int next = 0;
2336              boolean limited = limit > 0;
2337              ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
2338              while ((next = indexOf(ch, off)) != -1) {
2339                  if (!limited || list.size() < limit - 1) {
2340                      list.add(substring(off, next));
2341                      off = next + 1;
2342                  } else {    // last one
2343                      //assert (list.size() == limit - 1);
2344                      list.add(substring(off, value.length));
2345                      off = value.length;
2346                      break;
2347                  }
2348              }
2349              // If no match was found, return this
2350              if (off == 0)
2351                  return new String[]{this};
2353              // Add remaining segment
2354              if (!limited || list.size() < limit)
2355                  list.add(substring(off, value.length));
2357              // Construct result
2358              int resultSize = list.size();
2359              if (limit == 0) {
2360                  while (resultSize > 0 && list.get(resultSize - 1).length() == 0) {
2361                      resultSize--;
2362                  }
2363              }
2364              String[] result = new String[resultSize];
2365              return list.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
2366          }
2367          return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
2368      }
```

where you can find

```
if (off == 0)
    return new String[]{this};
```

fragment which means

- `if (off == 0)` - if `off` (position from which method should start searching for next possible match for regex passed as `split` argument) is *still* `0` after iterating over entire string, we didn't find any match, so the string was not split
- `return new String[]{this};` - in that case let's just return an array with original string (represented by `this`).

Since `","` couldn't be found in `""` even once, `"".split(",")` must return an array with one element (empty string on which you invoked `split`). This means that the length of this array is `1`.

BTW. Java 8 introduced another mechanism. It removes *leading empty strings (if they ware created while splitting process)* if we split using [zero-length regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html) (like `""` or with look-around `(?<!x)`). More info at: [Why in Java 8 split sometimes removes empty strings at start of result array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-in-java-8-split-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-at-start-of-result-array)

Comment: Sorry about the off-topic comment, but may I ask how you generated that code block with line numbers and formatting?

Comment: @Bob When you hover your mouse over line number at grepcode you would see `<>`. When you click it you will open box in which you can specify range of lines you want to get as HTML code.

Comment: Ah, a bit unfortunate that it's grepcode-specific, but still pretty nice. Thanks.

Comment: @Pshemo **1)** Then why `"".split("").length` is `1`. How is it different from `",".split(",").length` ? **2)** `" ".split("").length` is `1` as regex `""` cannot be found in `" "`. Seems OK. **3)** But  how come `"  ".split("").length` is `2`? **4)** Also how come both `"a  ".split("").length` and 
`"a a".split("").length` is `3`? In this case, why `""` is matching in between and not the start. If it also matches at start length would be `4`.  **5)** What I want to know is, when should I match regex `""` with the given string and when shouldn't I match?

Comment: @Pshemo **5)** Also `" ".split(" ").length` is `0`. regex `" "` was found in string `" "` , all trailing were removed and hence. Seems OK.  

**6)** But  how come `"  ".split(" ").length` is `0`? **a)** why regex `" "` (1 space) cannot be found in `"  "`(2 spaces). **b)** Even if there is no match, shouldn't the length be `1`? because, entire string `"  "` should have got stored as one element in that array.

**7)** And `"a  ".split(" ").length` is `1` but array has `[a]`. `"  a".split(" ").length` is `3` but array has `[, , a]`. Very confusing.

Comment: @Pshemo 
**8)** When should I match regex `" "` with the given string and when shouldn't I match?

Comment: @AbhinavVutukuri To answer your questions I would need more than one comment. Could you post these examples as separate question (or questions)? Also it may be important to point out what version of Java you are using. Judging by your profile picture it may be Android which can be using Java 7 instead of Java 8 where you can get little different results.

Comment: @AbhinavVutukuri Anyway in short, you can think that Java assumes that you can't split `""` farther, so for each `"".split(whatever)` you will always get `[""]` array. In case of `",".split(",")` regex matches entire string so at first you are getting `["", ""]` array which then removes trailing empty strings, leaving empty array so its length is `0` not `2` (I don't know where did you get that value from). `" ".split("")` in Java 8 gives me `[" "]`. Originally it was `["", " ", ""]` - empty string exists at start and end of string. Trailing empty string ware removed, leading in Java 8.

Comment: @Pshemo I have posted a new question with full details. link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41449791/2818583. I am using **Java 8 u112**. All code was complied and ran using intellij idea software: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/. In case of  `",".split(",")` I also got length as '0'. **2)** in my comment signifies **question 2**. Not length of the array. I was asking how `"".split("").` is different from `",".split(",")`. You explained that clearly in your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the seconda argument `-1` hint. I was stumped until I read it since I required equal length arrays and not collapsing due to missing values between separators.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Java 1.7 Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

> Splits the string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> split() method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

In the Case 1 `blank.split(",") does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this String.`

`It will return entire String.` So, the length will be `1`.

In the Case 2 `comma.split(",") will return empty.`

`split()` expecting a regex as argument, return result array to matching with that regex.

So, the length is `0`

**For Example**([Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29))

> The string **"boo:and:foo"**, yields the following results with these expressions:

```
Regex     Result
  :     { "boo", "and", "foo" }
  o     { "b", "", ":and:f" }
```

> **Parameters:**
>      regex - the delimiting regular expression
>
> **Returns:**
>      the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches of the given regular expression
>
> **Throws:**
>      PatternSyntaxException - if the regular expression's syntax is invalid

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: *split(",") will return empty* : this is what requires an explanation!

Comment: @ring0 **comma.split(",") will return empty.
`split()` expecting a regex as argument, return result array to matching with that regex. So, the length is 0**

Answer (score 4):

From String class [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) for the `public String[] split(String regex)` method:

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

In the first case, the expression does not match any part of the input so we got an array with only one element - the input.

In the second case, the expression matches input and split should return two empty strings; but, according to javadoc, they are discarded (because they are trailing and empty).

Comment: +1 This is the (umm; counting on my fingers here) *sixth* answer that says *what* result gets returned – and the ***first*** one that explains ***why***.

Answer (score 3):

We can take a look into [the source code of `java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/677a0ad1e733/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java) which is behind `String.split`. Way down the rabbit hole the method

```
public String[] split(CharSequence input, int limit)
```

is invoked.

### Input `""`

For input `""` this method is called as

```
String[] parts = split("", 0);
```

[The intersting part of this method is](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/677a0ad1e733/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l1193):

```
  int index = 0;
  boolean matchLimited = limit > 0;
  ArrayList<String> matchList = new ArrayList<>();
  Matcher m = matcher(input);

  while(m.find()) {
    // Tichodroma: this will not happen for our input
  }

  // If no match was found, return this
  if (index == 0)
    return new String[] {input.toString()};
```

And that is what happens: [`new String[] {input.toString()}` is returned](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/677a0ad1e733/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l1213).

### Input `","`

For input `","`[the intersting part is](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/677a0ad1e733/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l1221)

```
    // Construct result
    int resultSize = matchList.size();
    if (limit == 0)
        while (resultSize > 0 && matchList.get(resultSize-1).equals(""))
            resultSize--;
    String[] result = new String[resultSize];
    return matchList.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
```

Here `resultSize == 0` and `limit == 0` so [`new String[0]` is returned](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/677a0ad1e733/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#l1226).

Comment: I believe that your last sentence is an oversimplification, so much so that it cripples the value of your answer. The ***interesting*** (i.e., *relevant*) part is lines 1223-1225. Entering line 1223, `resultSize` is `2`, because `matchList` is { `""`, `""` }. But, *because* `limit` is `0` (the default when `split` is called with only one parameter), the loop at lines 1224-1225 gets invoked, and it iterates twice, discarding the two null strings and decrementing `resultSize` to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

From JDK 1.7

```
 public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
        /* fastpath if the regex is a
           (1)one-char String and this character is not one of the
              RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or
           (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and
              the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.
        */
        char ch = 0;
        if (((regex.count == 1 &&
             ".$|()[{^?*+\\".indexOf(ch = regex.charAt(0)) == -1) ||
             (regex.length() == 2 &&
              regex.charAt(0) == '\\' &&
              (((ch = regex.charAt(1))-'0')|('9'-ch)) < 0 &&
              ((ch-'a')|('z'-ch)) < 0 &&
              ((ch-'A')|('Z'-ch)) < 0)) &&
            (ch < Character.MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE ||
             ch > Character.MAX_LOW_SURROGATE))
        {
            int off = 0;
            int next = 0;
            boolean limited = limit > 0;
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while ((next = indexOf(ch, off)) != -1) {
                if (!limited || list.size() < limit - 1) {
                    list.add(substring(off, next));
                    off = next + 1;
                } else {    // last one
                    //assert (list.size() == limit - 1);
                    list.add(substring(off, count));
                    off = count;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If no match was found, return this
            if (off == 0)
                return new String[] { this };

            // Add remaining segment
            if (!limited || list.size() < limit)
                list.add(substring(off, count));

            // Construct result
            int resultSize = list.size();
            if (limit == 0)
                while (resultSize > 0 && list.get(resultSize-1).length() == 0)
                    resultSize--;
            String[] result = new String[resultSize];
            return list.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
        }
        return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
    }
```

So for this case, the regex will be handled by the first `if`.

For the first case `blank.split(",")`

```
// If no match was found, return this
if (off == 0)
   return new String[] { this };
```

So, this function will return an array which contains one element if there is no matched.

For the second case `comma.split(",")`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
//...
int resultSize = list.size();
if (limit == 0)
    while (resultSize > 0 && list.get(resultSize-1).length() == 0)
           resultSize--;
String[] result = new String[resultSize];
return list.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
```

As you notice, the last while loop has removed all empty element in the end of the list, so the resultSize is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String blank = "";                    
String comma = ",";                   
System.out.println("Output1: "+blank.split(",").length);  // case 1
System.out.println("Output2: "+comma.split(",").length);  // case 2
```

case 1 - Here `blank.split(",")` will return `""` since there is no `,` in `blank` you get the same, So length will be `1`

case 2- Here `comma.split(",")` will return empty array, you have to scape `,` if you want to count `comma` with length `1` else length will be `0`

Again `comma.split(",")` split() expecting a `regex` as argument it will return result array to matching with that `regex`.

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this
>   string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given
>   expression or is terminated by the end of the string.

Else

> If the expression does not match any part of the input then the
>   resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

Comment: please explain case 1 broadly

Comment: The question is why it is returned `""` ?

Answer (score 1):

The API for the split method states that "If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string."

So, as the String blank doesn't contain a ",", a String[] with one element (i.e. blank itself) is returned.

For the String comma, "nothing" is left of the original string thus an empty array is returned.

This seems to be the best solution if you want to process the returned result, e. g.

```
String[] splits = aString.split(",");
for(String split: splits) {
   // do something
}
```