# After we split a String via RegEx, how could we get the length of new String?

Tags: regex, string, split

```
public class TestString {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "AaaaABBBBcc&^%adfsfdCCOOkk99876 _haHA";
    String[] upStr = str.split("[a-z0-9&^% _]");
    System.out.println("Printout uppercase");

    for (String outUp : upStr){
        System.out.print(outUp);
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + upStr.length);
```

The "length" is wrong, so, where does the value comes from?
How could we get real length?

```
    System.out.println("\n Printout lowercase");
    String[] lowStr = str.split("[A-Z0-9&^% _]");
    for (String outLow : lowStr){
        System.out.print(outLow);
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + lowStr.length);

    System.out.println("\n non-English");
    String[] nonEng = str.split("[A-Za-z]");
    for (String outNonEng : nonEng){
        System.out.print(outNonEng);
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + nonEng.length);
```

So my question is:

1. The value of the length is incorrect, but where is is comes from?
2. How could I get correct length of `String[]`?

Comment: length seems correct

Comment: I will suggest you to read :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/22259885/1996394

Comment: Printout uppercase
AABBBBCCOOHA
in fact the current length is 12;
 Printout lowercase
aaaccadfsfdkkha
 non-English
&^%99876 _

Comment: `length` in this case is the number of items in the array. How come you're talking about "length of new string"?

Comment: Base on the Java API: String[]  split(String regex)
Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression. After we use the "split", it will return a String[] back.

Comment: Do not split, use `replaceAll("[^A-Z]+", "").length` to check uppercase letter count and `replaceAll("[^a-z]+", "").length` to check lowercase letter count.

Comment: Yes, and is it the *length* of the array you're talking about? (Please add the output of your code to make it easier to help you + use `@username` to alert people when you reply ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to do it like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "AaaaABBBBcc&^%adfsfdCCOOkk99876 _haHA";
        String[] upStr = str.replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "").split("(?!^)");
        String[] lowStr = str.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").split("(?!^)");
        String[] nonEng = str.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", "").split("(?!^)");
        System.out.println("Printout uppercase");
        printResult(upStr);
        System.out.println("\nPrintout lowercase");
        printResult(lowStr);
        System.out.println("\nPrintout non-English");
        printResult(nonEng);   
    }
public static void printResult(String[] array) {
        for (String outChar : array){
        System.out.print(outChar);
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + array.length);
}
```

Output:

```
Printout uppercase
AABBBBCCOOHA
12

Printout lowercase
aaaccadfsfdkkha
15

Printout non-English
&^%99876 _
10
```